# Sublime Text snippet convert camelCase to snake_case

Tags: php, regex, perl, sublimetext3, code-snippets

Hi there I am trying to make an sublime text snippet and i would like to 
convert an camelCase word to snake_case. I do know there are plugins that allow you to convert string to snake_case but i want to do it through sublime text snippets.

I have a snippet like below.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
/**
 * ${TM_FILEPATH/^.+\/(\w+)\.php$/${1}/} belongs to many (many-to-many) ${1/^((.+)ies)|(.+[^s])s$/\u(?1$2y:$3)/}.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function $1()
{
    return \$this->belongsToMany('App\\${1/^((.+)ies)|(.+[^s])s$/\u(?1$2y:$3)/}', '${TM_FILEPATH/^.+\/(\w+)\.php$/\l${1}/}_$1', '${TM_FILEPATH/^.+\/(\w+)\.php$/\l${1}/}_id', '${1/^((.+)ies)|(.+[^s])s$/\l(?1$2y:$3)/}_id');
}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>btm</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.php</scope>
    <description>Eloquent belongsToMany() (pivot) relation</description>
</snippet>
```

And as an output it gives me.

```
 /**
     * UserMessages belongs to many (many-to-many) Role.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'userMessages_roles', 'userMessages_id', 'role_id');
    }
```

What i want to end up is the userMessages to be user_messages.
Any idea how to accomplish that.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An example of a snippet that does something like this is the following, based on your example but shortened up for clarity (also I changed the scope to `embedding.php` so it would trigger with the syntax that I use for PHP). You should be able to adapt this to your needs in your larger snippet example.

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
// ${1/^([A-Z])|(?:([A-Z]))/(?1\l$1:)(?2_\l$2:)/g}
public function ${1}()
{
    $0
}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>btm</tabTrigger>
    <scope>embedding.php</scope>
    <description>Eloquent belongsToMany() (pivot) relation</description>
</snippet>
```

[image: Example of snippet in use]

The basis of this can be seen in the [snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) page in the [unofficial documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/). The expansion of a variable in a snippet takes the form `${variable/regex/format_string/options}`. The regex uses the [boost library regular expressions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) and [format strings](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html).

Boost supports conditional replacement in the form of `(?Ntrue:false)`, where for capture group `N` the replacement text is `true` if the match captured something or `false` if it did not.

Here we use an alternation in the regular expression to have two capture groups, so that we can supply two different replacements depending on which of the items matches. The first capture group captures a leading uppercase character and just transforms it to lower case, while the second one (not anchored to the start of the line) does the same and also precedes the match with an underscore.

Comment: I find doing the lc first letter in a capture group a lot less readable, the regex becomes a lot more complicated that way. Quite unnecessarily.

Comment: Hi Odat Nurd
This does what i want however i want the file name without extension to be snake_case.
This is almost perfect ``` ${TM_FILENAME/^([A-Z])|(?:([A-Z]))/(?1\l$1:)(?2_\l$2:)/g} ``` just need to get rid of .php at the end.

Comment: For that, I would try `${TM_FILENAME/^([A-Z])|(?:([A-Z]))|(?:\.\w+)/(?1\l$1:)(?2_\l$2:)(?3:)/g}` which is the above but with a capture group that matches a file extension and then throws it away. It may take some additional tuning if your files have periods in them though.

Answer (score 2):

Perl offers the `\L` modifier to lower case a capture when replacing.
The captures are in brackets () and can be backreferenced by $1, $2, etc.

So all that's needed is to find a lower case character followed by an upper case character, which should then be lower cased.

```
sub camel_case_to_underscore {
    my $method_name = shift;   
    $method_name =~s /([a-z])([A-Z])/$1_\L$2/g;
    return lcfirst $method_name;
}
```

The `g` flag replaces globally, so all occurrences in the string.

Note that this function lower cases the first letter of the string as well,
I assume that's what you want.